# Unable to access data using javascript variable in pdo database in php

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

Here in my php variable `$eventId` which is accessing value using JavaScript and is called in `<span>` element by `class='id'`

```
$eventId = "<span class='id'></span>";
```

and I am getting the value of `$eventId` by echoing it;

```
echo $eventId . "<br />";
```

But I am unable to access the value of this variable in PDO Using `get()` function from the database

```
$evntImg = db::getInstance()->get("db_table", array("table_id", "=", $eventId));
```

Comment: `$eventId` is currently a string. It should be an `int`. Try setting the variable as (for id = 3 for example) `$eventID = 3`

Comment: May have to do with how it's being encoded -- maybe the backticks and the quotes are messing it up somehow?

Comment: You should let us know what database library you're using. That's not just plain "PDO". Also, the code suggests that you're trying to match `table_id` with the string `<span class='id'></span>`.

Comment: According to your code `$eventId` would be an HTML element string resulting in your query looking like `WHERE table_id = "<span class='id'></span>"`. In addition,  PHP is executed on the server side, while Javascript is executed on the client side and can not interact with PHP. How is your Javascript sending data to PHP?

Comment: ooo... Thanks a lot its wright that   PHP is executed on the server side, while Javascript is executed on the client side and can not interact with PHP Said my "fyrye" thanks a lot fyre, can you plz convert the variable so that it can be accessed by the server...